# How to prevent texts inside form from shifting?

Tags: java, forms, itext7

In iText 7 you can create acro forms, as described at https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-java/chapter-4-making-pdf-interactive.

You can also provide the field with a value, which can be edited by the user.

But when you do this, the text shifts position as soon as the user enters that field.
When the user is done editing, the text doesn't shift back to its original position.

```java
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
document.add(new Paragraph("Form").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(16));
document.add(new Paragraph("Full Name").setFontSize(12));

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(99, 753.5F, 425, 15);
// I provide a default value of 
PdfTextFormField nameField = PdfTextFormField.createText(pdfDoc, rect, "name", "My default name");
form.addField(nameField);


// I draw some shapes to make the problem more obvious.
float offset = 65;
rect.setX(rect.getX() - offset);
rect.setWidth(rect.getWidth() + offset);
new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getLastPage())
    .rectangle(rect)
    .setStrokeColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)
    .setLineWidth(0.5F)
    .moveTo(rect.getX(), rect.getY() + 4)
    .lineTo(rect.getX() + rect.getWidth(), rect.getY() + 4)
    .stroke();

pdfDoc.close();

Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(DEST));
```

[image]
In the image above you can see that the text is lined out neatly.

[image]
In the image above the user has started editing the field. It's no longer neatly aligned

[image]
In the image above, the user is done editing. The text did not restore to it's original position.

In this example, the effect is quite minimal.
But depending on the dimensions of the field, this can be quite dramatic.
Especially in tables in can be jarring.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I doubt there's a solution to that, different Acrobat versions will shift differently too.

Comment: Ah. If it depends on 3rd party software, then it's game over. In that case we'll just have to live with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Itext uses a dynamic font size that needs to be static height so make the fields taller and or longer. Works well in Viewers, but not when a user is editing.

[image]

Interesting to note in a  blog from iText

> in iText 7. This specific workflow for using substitution fonts was no longer available in iText 7 because the PDF specifications for 1.7 and 2.0 actually limit the visual representation of a field to a single style. As Chapter 8 – Interactive Features of the PDF 1.7 Reference notes regarding form fields:

> The field’s text is held in a text string (or, beginning with PDF 1.5, a stream) in the V (value) entry of the field dictionary. The contents of this text string or stream shall be used to construct an appearance stream for displaying the field, as described under 12.7.3.3, “Variable Text.” The text shall be presented in a single style (font, size, color, and so forth), as specified by the DA (default appearance) string.

Since you do not know what font style a user system editor is defaulting to. Presume you need to leave enough space for any substitution at one generous height, without any underlining.

Due to the way some PDF viewers need to use form and body text, you may even see double text due to the different appearances placements, look at the iText positioning on the left.  Arguably a reader displacement, but the main issue is the normalised text on the right looks lower.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you still need the answer to this, but if you do:

```
form.SetNeedAppearances(true);
```

That should fix the text shifting.